# Leverage browser caching not working on local plugin javascript

Tags: javascript, caching, pagespeed, http-caching, google-pagespeed

I have added the following code to my .htaccess file:

```
# JS/CSS files - 4 hours
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

But PageSpeed Insights still says I need to Leverage Browser Caching for:

```
…assets/js/jquery.dop.ThumbnailGallery.js (4 hours)
…g/libraries/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js (4 hours)
…/doptg/libraries/js/jquery.mousewheel.js (4 hours)
…rati_nextgen/modules/ajax/static/ajax.js (4 hours)
…nextgen/modules/ajax/static/ngg_store.js (4 hours)
…i_nextgen/modules/ajax/static/persist.js (4 hours)
…ati_nextgen/modules/ajax/static/store.js (4 hours)
…ules/lightbox/static/lightbox_context.js (4 hours)
…tent/plugins/page-list/css/page-list.css (4 hours)
…ugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js (4 hours)
…n/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js (4 hours)
```

All of these are local files in a plugins folder, so the Cache-Control should work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct with 14400 it should do 4 hours of caching.

PageSpeed suggest to keeps it more, increase it for a day and verify.